# NOT NULL constraint failed: django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

estoy obteniendo un error cuando trato de crear un nuevo elemento por parte de un formulario, tratando de que el usuario que ya se encuentra con la sesión iniciada pueda subir una imagen y esta sea reconocida como suya en la relación con la base de datos que tengo en el `models.py`.

```
NOT NULL constraint failed: pins_pin.user_id
```

models.py

```
class Pin(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/img/pins')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

forms.py

```
from .models import Pin

class PinCreateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Pin
        fields = ('title', 'image')
```

views.py

```
class PinCreate(CreateView):
    model = Pin
    form_class = PinCreateForm
    template_name = 'pins/pin_create.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = self.request.user
        form.save()
        return redirect('/')
```

Gracias de antemano a quien pueda ayudarme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

deberia ser:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.user = self.request.user
    return redirect('/')
```

Comment: oooh, asi que `form.instance` es donde esta guardado todos los campos del formulario! Gracias!